# Error from server (BadRequest): container "<containername>" in pod "<podname>" is waiting to start: ErrImageNeverPull

Tags: docker, kubernetes, blazor, minikube

there are use local image on my pc in local server show this error this below

Error from server (BadRequest): container "blazorserverdocker" in pod "blazorserverdocker-deployment-59db5d5675-ffh9w" is waiting to start: ErrImageNeverPull

This error show in poweshell like this below image[image]

I am using kubernetes and minikube

this is below deployment.yml file

[image]

this is below docker images

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)  Can you [edit] the question to replace all of the images with their plain-text equivalents?  What sort of Kubernetes are you using; if it's not Docker Desktop, how is the image getting there?

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that Docker images you see in "docker images" output are different from what Kubernetes sees. Minikube has its own in-cluster Docker daemon. So you need to push your images to Minikube Docker registry.

Simply speaking it can be done like this in Powershell:

```
> minikube docker-env --shell powershell | Invoke-Expression
> docker push YOUR_DOCKER_IMAGE
```

You can read more about it here: https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/pushing/#1-pushing-directly-to-the-in-cluster-docker-daemon-docker-env

Comment: try your solution but not working , any another solution?